# Migrate Eclipse CDT to other IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, ide, codeblocks

Is there a way to migrate eclipse CDT (C/C++) project setting to other lightweight IDE like CodeBlocks/CodeLite/Netbeans or any other freeware C/C++ IDE. I feel eclipse is slow and navigation is not so good compared to Visual Studio.

Comment: for netbeans  https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/import-eclipse.html

Comment: I encourage you to submit questions or bug reports on the slowness you are experiencing in CDT. There are very likely things that can easily be done to improve your overall CDT experience.